# How would I ensure of a emergency recovery method of root account is possible in GCP?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

Hey I'm a newbie with GCP and I am trying to do some audit work on security controls for a company at an org level and need help on my question. Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to explain a bit more what you mean with root account (the actual root user on a linux VM? Or some IAM admin?) and what "emergency recovery" means

Comment: Please invest time in your question. Google Cloud Platform does not have **root** accounts. The concept of a root account derives from Unix and its offspring. If you are trying to prevent and recover from compromises, then you need to know precisely what you are securing. Your question is better suited for the Stackexchange Security site.

Comment: Thank you both very much. And thank you for that John. I didnt know that GCP does not have root accounts.

Comment: Note, the Linux operating system has a root user. Windows has Administrator.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.